# When to use EMR or Scan for Amazon's Dynamo-DB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Both EMR and Scan will parse the entire table and consume request credits but EMR will also need to use ec2 instances thus costing much more.

So, I am wondering in which case EMR is better suited than Scan on Amazon's Dynamo-DB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry - I'm not entirely sure I understand your question.

If you are asking why you would use EMR to scan an entire DynamoDB table versus just doing a scan directly the answer is speed and simplicity.

If you use something like Hive with the DynamoDB Serde, you can extract the entire contents of your DynamoDB table much faster than querying DynamoDB directly because the scan is going to be parallelised.

DynamoDB supports consistent read performance so more often than not, when querying a DynamoDB table, the bottleneck shifts to the client being able to read data fast enough.